# Alternating background color per 3 entries in the list

Tags: django, django-templates

i have a problem in alternating the color of background, blue and white, in my tr tag.. here's my code: I am running django 1.1.1

```
{% for item in results %}
{% if forloop.counter0|divisibleby:3 %}<tr>{% endif %}
    <td>{{ item }}</td>
{% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:3 %}</tr>{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

do you have any idea on how to do this? the output should be something like this

```
<tr style=" bacground-color: blue" >
    <td> list1 </td>
    <td> list2 </td>
    <td> list3 </td>
</tr>
<tr style=" bacground-color: white" >
    <td> list4 </td>
    <td> list5 </td>
    <td> list6 </td>
</tr>
```

I can generate that output list beside the background-color alternating..

any help/ideas guys on how to solve my problem.. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
background-color: {% cycle 'blue' 'blue' 'blue' 'white' 'white' 'white' %}
```

Comment: thanks that solve my problem.. hehe.. now i know the logic on how to use cycle.. :) thanks to you.. this code solve my problem:

Answer (score 1):

here's the full code in solving the problem:

```
{% for item in results %}
{% if forloop.counter0|divisibleby:3 %}<tr style=" bacground-color: {% cycle 'blue'  'white' %}">{% endif %}
    <td>{{ item }}</td>
{% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:3 %}</tr>{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

thanks to Ignacio for the very fast reply.. :)